# Where to find the documentation of the SUBQUERY feature of NSPredicate for Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Where to find the documentation of the SUBQUERY feature of NSPredicate for Core Data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question... it seems like this isn't well documented.

Here is what I found:

- The most documentation can be found at **[NSExpression(forSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:) documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:)**. It contains two examples and the syntax: `SUBQUERY(collection_expression, variable_expression, predicate);`
- [NSExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/index.html) briefly mentions **Subquery Expressions** and the `NSSubqueryExpressionType`, which is what is used when you specify `SUBQUERY` in your predicate.
- The most logical place to find the documentation would be the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates), but it is just mentioned a few times; in the [String Comparisons](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868), and the [Reserved Words](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-213522) sections.
- You can try a [Google search limited to apple.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=nspredicate+subquery+site:apple.com+-inurl:lists), but this only returns 53 results.

**Update:**

With the addition of App Extensions, Apple has included more SUBQUERY examples since they are required for complex matching logic.

- In the [String Comparisons](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868) section of the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates), it now includes an example of how to match a UTI:

  ```
   SUBQUERY (
       extensionItems,
       $extensionItem,
       SUBQUERY (
           $extensionItem.attachments,
           $attachment,
           ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
       ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
   ).@count == 1
  ```
- You can find a more complex example in the App Extension Programming Guide > App Extension Essentials > [Handling Common Scenarios section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1):

  ```
   SUBQUERY (
       extensionItems,
       $extensionItem,
       SUBQUERY (
           $extensionItem.attachments,
           $attachment,
           ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "org.appextension.action-one" ||
           ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "org.appextension.action-two"
       ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
   ).@count == 1
  ```
- There's also an [NSPredicate Cheatsheet](https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) which discusses SUBQUERY in addition to several other NSPredicate features.

---

Essentially each `SUBQUERY` is equivalent to `filter` in Swift. And `ANY` is equivalent to `contains`.

So taking this example again:

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
    ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
).@count == 1
```

It would be similar to this in Swift:

```
extensionItems.filter {
  $0.attachments.filter {
    $0.registeredTypeIdentifiers.contains {
      $0.utiConformsTo("com.adobe.pdf")
    }
  }.count == $0.attachments.count
}.count == 1
```

Comment: Indeed it seems that this feature is entirely undocumented. What a pitty - seems to be so cool. I can only guess: They fear that people over-use this, since it seems to be something reall, really heavy.

Comment: Or not enough people have filed a radar with apple to make it important enough to document.  If you want to see documentation on this feature, file a radar.