# NSPredicate for a Core Data Search

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have 3 `NSManagedObjet`s; Person, Stuff, and Collection.

[image]

I want to use a `NSPredicate` to get a list of all `Collection`s that `ThePerson` has.

Example: Scott has objectA and objectB which are in collection Letters and object1 which is in collection Numbers.

I want to be able to do a fetch request and get back collection Letters and Numbers.

I tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY stuffs.persons == %@", person];
```

And:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(stuffs, $s, ANY $s.persons == %@)", scott];
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SUBQUERY` syntax is wrong (for a full explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813608/115730) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9637314/115730)).  It should be something like:

```
SUBQUERY(stuffs, $s, ANY $s.persons == %@).@count > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that you already have a reference to a `ThePerson` object, you don't need to do a fetch or use a predicate. You can traverse the relationships you've declared to get the collections. You can get all of the `Collection`s that `ThePerson` has by using:

```
NSSet *collections = [person valueForKeyPath:@"stuffs.collections"];
```

Comment: There is another condition that I forgot to mention: Scott's Letter `Collection` may contain objectA and objectB, while Jen's Letter Collection may only contain objectA. With that requirement, I don't believe this solution would work? Or would I be wrong? I'm sorry I didn't state this in the question originally.