# How to make a compatible password extension?

Tags: ios, url-scheme, ios-app-extension

Both 1Password and LastPass utilize the same scheme (`org-appextension-feature-password-management`) for password management. This allows 3rd party apps to use the [onepassword-app-extension](https://github.com/AgileBits/onepassword-app-extension) to work with any of these password managers.

If I want to implement my own password manager which is compatible with this extension, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

To implement a password manager:

1. Add a new target to your project. Choose "Action Extension."
2. Add `org-appextension-feature-password-management` as a URL Scheme (`CFBundleURLSchemes`) that your app supports.

   You can do this in the Info tab of your target. The scheme is the important part. The [identifier doesn't seem to be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597631/url-identifier-and-url-scheme).

   This is required so that `-[OnePasswordExtension isAppExtensionAvailable]` will return true.
3. In your app extension's target, change the `NSExtensionActivationRule` from `TRUEPREDICATE` to the following:

   ```
   SUBQUERY (
     extensionItems,
     $extensionItem,
     SUBQUERY (
       $extensionItem.attachments,
       $attachment,
       ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "org.appextension.find-login-action"
     ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
   ).@count == 1
   ```

   This will make sure your extension only appears if the `-[OnePasswordExtension findLoginForURLString:forViewController:sender:completion:]` method is called. If you want to match more than one of these UTIs, see [Apple's more complex example here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1).

   Note: This SUBQUERY is the same as [Apple's SUBQUERY example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1), with the constant changed. If you're wondering about the syntax or how it works, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076702/35690).
4. To read which url should be filled:

   ```
   let inputItem = extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as! NSExtensionItem
   let inputItemProvider = inputItem.attachments![0] as! NSItemProvider

   inputItemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "org.appextension.find-login-action", options: nil) { (data, err) in
       if let err = err { fatalError("\(err)") }

       let urlString = (data as! NSDictionary)["url_string"] as! String
   }
   ```
5. When you're ready to send data from the extension back to the host app:

   ```
   let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(
       item: ["username": "foo", "password": "123"],
       typeIdentifier:kUTTypePropertyList as String) // TODO: import MobileCoreServices

   let extensionItem = NSExtensionItem()
   extensionItem.attachments = [itemProvider]

   extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([extensionItem], completionHandler: nil)
   ```

---

If you're wondering why it's okay to register these schemes, you can [read this article](https://blog.agilebits.com/2014/08/04/filling-with-your-approval-on-1passwords-app-extension-and-ios-8-security/):

> Our brand-neutral scheme should make things easier both for users and for app developers. Thus, part of our reason for using a brand neutral scheme is to **encourage as many app developers as possible to use this scheme.** We aren’t forcing app developers to choose between 1Password and some competitor. Instead, we are delegating the choice of which password manager to use to where that choice belongs: you.

Comment: Can you provide more details. There is 19 different Application Extension types, which one is used for creating password manager?