# How to monitor and interact with login forms without a foreground process in iOS app development?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, background, foreground-service

Is there a way to run a perpetual task from an iPhone application that monitors the view for login forms?

This is apparently *possible* given apps like dashlane, lastpass, etc. which recognize login forms and offer options to interact with them, however according to [most documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329653/ios-equivalent-to-android-service), apple doesn't seem to allow this type of continuous service.

How are these other apps accomplishing perpetual background processes in iOS applications?

Comment: I think you'd need to build an extension - which type, I can't say, but I think that might be where you need to start

Comment: [How to make a compatible password extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819916/how-to-make-a-compatible-password-extension) might help